# Enter Teams ConversationID for my Incoming Webhook

Tags: json, post, postman, webhooks, microsoft-teams

I addded an `Incoming Webhook` to my Teams Channel. When making a `POST` to my Webhook I get my MessageCard on Teams. This is my json:

```
{
        "@type": "MessageCard",
        "themeColor": "0072C6",
        "title": "Placeholder",
        "text": "Placeholder",
          "from": {
      "id": "myid",
      "name": "myname" 
  }
}
```

Now the ConversationID of the Webhook looks similar to this:

```
19:22abc7ur64z8428kg592z33p993dhen3@thread.skype;messageid=933334115313
```

Now here is my problem: I can only know about how the ConversationID looks like when the Webhook posts the MessageCard on Teams. And I wondered:

Can I edit my json so that I decide what the ConversationID of this post will be?

Example on how I could imagine my json:

```
{
        "@type": "MessageCard",
        "themeColor": "0072C6",
        "title": "Ein WebBot konnte eine Frage nicht Beantworten",
        "text": "Placeholder",
          "from": {
      "id": "botdg@Dxq6fxrkMAI",
      "name": "teams",
  },
      "conversation": {
    "id": "19:22abc7ur64z8428kg592z33p993dhen3@thread.skype;messageid=585269569213"
  }
}
```

Comment: No, You can not set the conversation id in message payload. What is your scenario?

Comment: looking for same, Use Case -Add Conversation to existing Chat Message as Answer